# Robot Framework - AWS API Gateway secured by IAM

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, robotframework, aws-api-gateway

**Background**

I've been using [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) and [RequestsLibrary](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) to write automated tests against RESTful endpoints I expose via AWS API Gateway.  So I'm writing tests that look roughly like this:

```
*** Settings ***                
Library Collections
Library RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***              
Get Requests
    Create Session  Sess    https://<api-gateway-url>   
    ${resp}=    Get Request Sess    /path/to/my/api?param=value 
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code} 200 
    Dictionary Should Contain Value ${resp.json()}  someValueIwantToVerify
```

Now, I'm getting around to securing those API Gateway endpoints with IAM.  Therefore requests need to be [sig4 signed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

The application that consumes these services is written in javascript, and uses [aws-api-gateway-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client) to sign requests.  Testing (manually) in Postman is also easy enough, using `AWS Signature` Authorization type.  However, I'm struggling with figuring out a strategy for Robot Framework.

**Question(s)**

In the broadest sense, I'm wondering if anyone else is using Robot Framework to test IAM secured API Gateway endpoints.  If so, how did you pull it off?

More specifically:

- Is there an existing Robot Framework library that addresses this use case?
- If not, is writing my own library my only option?
- If I am stuck writing a library ([this looks promising](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth)), what sorts of keywords would I define, and how would I use them?

Comment: I'm still open to ideas; not married to RequestsLibrary.  Please add an answer or comment if you have *anything* to contribute.  That said, this is a reflection of my current thinking:  https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/issues/184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requests` library accepts an `auth` parameter, which is expected to be a subclass of [`AuthBase`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-authentication).

It turns out that modifying `RequestsLibrary` to leverage this existing functionality was a grand total of two lines of code (not counting comments, tests, and whitespace for readability):

```
def create_custom_session(self, alias, url, auth, headers={}, cookies=None, timeout=None, proxies=None, verify=False, debug=0, max_retries=3, backoff_factor=0.10, disable_warnings=0):
    return self._create_session(alias, url, headers, cookies, auth, timeout, max_retries, backoff_factor, proxies, verify, debug, disable_warnings)
```

Sometimes the answer is just to [issue your own pull request](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/pull/186).

The new `Create Custom Session` keyword will accept any arbitrary `auth` object, including the one produced by the [library I'm using](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) (which I highly recommend).

The [original issue](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/issues/184) now contains the details of how [`aws-requests-auth`](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) and [`RequestsLibrary`](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) work together with the new keyword.

@the_mero mentioned `boto3` which is almost certainly what you want to use to actually marshal up the credentials.  You don't want to hard code them in your test like the simple examples in the issue/pull request do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an RF library that does what you want, but my first instinct would be to use Amazon's own AWS SDK for Python (boto3), and write a thin keyword wrapper library around it. I've done that for test cases that used AWS S3, but boto3 also supports API Gateway: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html